# Interrupt Handler Stops Working After Kernel Module Reload (Xilinx FPGA / PCIe)

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, fpga, kernel-module, pci-e

I am currently working on a PCI driver for the Xilinx Kintex 7 board using the Xilinx PCI IP core (AXI Memory Mapped to PCIe).
One problem is, that the interrupt handler stops working when I reload the kernel module. In more detail:

1. Fresh boot of my machine
2. Load the kernel module and monitor the kernel messages with `dmesg`
3. `/proc/interrupts` shows the expected interrupt ids
4. I trigger the HW interrupt and everything works as expected; I can see the interrupt handler working.
5. `rmmod my_module`
6. `/proc/interrupts` removed the interrupt ids as expected
7. `insmod my_module` and trigger interrupt
8. Now the interrupt handler is silent and `/proc/interrupts` does **not** increase the counter

I reboot my machine and everything works again. The fact that I do not have to restart the FPGA lets me assume that I do something wrong in the kernel module and its probably not an HW problem.

I've already used `/sys/pci/devices/.../reset`, `/sys/bus/pci/devices/.../remove` and `/sys/bus/pci/rescan` to try to reach a state which is equivalent to freshly booted machine. But nothing worked.

Relevant module code:

```c
#define VENDOR_ID 0x10EE
#define DEVICE_ID 0x7024

static dev_t pci_dev_number;
static struct cdev * driver_object;
static struct class * pci_class;
static struct device * pci_prc;
static struct device * pci_irq_0;
static struct device * pci_irq_1;

static int msi_vec_num = 2; // Number of requested MSI interrupts
static int msi_0 = -1;
static int msi_1 = -1;

// Used for poll and select
static DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(queue_vs0);
static DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(queue_vs1);

static irqreturn_t pci_isr_0(int irq, void * dev_id) {
  printk(KERN_NOTICE "codec IRQ: interrupt handler 0. IRQ: %d\n", irq);
  wake_up_interruptible(&queue_vs0);
  return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

static irqreturn_t pci_isr_1(int irq, void * dev_id) {
  printk(KERN_NOTICE "codec IRQ: interrupt handler 1. IRQ: %d\n", irq);
  wake_up_interruptible(&queue_vs1);
  return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

static void* bars[PCIE_BARS] = {0};

static int device_init(struct pci_dev * pdev, const struct pci_device_id * id) {
  int i = 0; // loop var
  if (pci_enable_device(pdev))
    return -EIO;

  // Request memory regions for bar 0 to 2
  for (i = 0; i < PCIE_BARS; i++) {
    if (pci_request_region(pdev, i, "codec_pci") != 0) {
      dev_err( & pdev - > dev, "Bar %d - I/O address conflict for device \"%s\"\n", i, pdev - > dev.kobj.name);
      return -EIO;
    }
  }

  // DEBUG: Check if we are in memory space (which we should) or io space
  if ((pci_resource_flags(pdev, 0) & IORESOURCE_IO)) {
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "codec INIT: in io space\n");
  } else if ((pci_resource_flags(pdev, 0) & IORESOURCE_MEM)) {
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "codec INIT: in mem_space\n");
  }

  // This request enables MSI_enable in the hardware
  msi_vec_num = pci_alloc_irq_vectors(pdev, 1, msi_vec_num, PCI_IRQ_MSI);

  // msi_N will contain the IRQ number - see /proc/interrupts
  msi_0 = pci_irq_vector(pdev, 0);
  msi_1 = pci_irq_vector(pdev, 1);
  printk(KERN_NOTICE "codec INIT: nvec: %d\n", msi_vec_num);
  printk(KERN_NOTICE "codec INIT: msi_0: %d\n", msi_0);
  printk(KERN_NOTICE "codec INIT: msi_1: %d\n", msi_1);

  if (request_irq(msi_0, pci_isr_0, IRQF_SHARED, "codec_pci", pdev)) {
    dev_err( & pdev - > dev, "codec INIT: IRQ MSI %d not free.\n", msi_0);
    goto cleanup;
  };
  if (request_irq(msi_1, pci_isr_1, IRQF_SHARED, "codec_pci", pdev)) {
    dev_err( & pdev - > dev, "codec INIT: IRQ MSI %d not free.\n", msi_1);
    goto cleanup;
  };

  for (i = 0; i < PCIE_BARS; i++) {
    // Last parameter is the address space/length of each bar. Defined in the PCIe core.
    bars[i] = pci_iomap(pdev, i, pci_resource_len(pdev, i));
    if (bars[i] == NULL) {
      printk(KERN_ERR "codec INIT: bar %d allocation failed\n", i);
      goto cleanup;
    }
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "codec INIT: bar %d pointer: %p\n", i, bars[i]);
  }

  printk(KERN_NOTICE "codec INIT: loaded\n");

  return 0;
cleanup:
    for (i = 0; i < PCIE_BARS; i++) {
      if (bars[i] != NULL)
        pci_iounmap(pdev, bars[i]);
      pci_release_region(pdev, i);
    }
    
  return -EIO;
}

static void device_deinit(struct pci_dev * pdev) {
  int i = 0; // loop var

  if (msi_0 >= 0)
    free_irq(msi_0, pdev);

  if (msi_1 >= 0)
    free_irq(msi_1, pdev);

  pci_free_irq_vectors(pdev);

  // release bar regions
  for (i = 0; i < PCIE_BARS; i++)
    pci_release_region(pdev, i);

  for (i = 0; i < PCIE_BARS; i++) {
    if (bars[i] != NULL)
      pci_iounmap(pdev, bars[i]);
  }
  pci_disable_device(pdev);
}

// File operations not in this snipped
static struct file_operations fops = {
  .owner = THIS_MODULE,
  .open = device_open,
  .read = device_read,
  .write = device_write,
  .poll = device_poll
};

static struct pci_device_id pci_drv_tbl[] = {
  {
    VENDOR_ID,
    DEVICE_ID,
    PCI_ANY_ID,
    PCI_ANY_ID,
    0,
    0,
    0
  },
  {
    0,
  }
};

static struct pci_driver pci_drv = {
  .name = "codec_pci",
  .id_table = pci_drv_tbl,
  .probe = device_init,
  .remove = device_deinit
};

static int __init mod_init(void) {
  int i = 0;
  if (alloc_chrdev_region( & pci_dev_number, 0, MAX_DEVICES, "codec_pci") < 0)
    return -EIO;
  driver_object = cdev_alloc();
  if (driver_object == NULL)
    goto free_dev_number;
  driver_object - > owner = THIS_MODULE;
  driver_object - > ops = & fops;
  if (cdev_add(driver_object, pci_dev_number, MAX_DEVICES))
    goto free_cdev;
  pci_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "codec_pci");
  if (IS_ERR(pci_class)) {
    pr_err("codec MOD_INIT: no udev support available\n");
    goto free_cdev;
  }

  pci_prc = device_create(pci_class, NULL, MKDEV(MAJOR(pci_dev_number), MINOR(pci_dev_number) + 0), NULL, "%s", "codec_prc");
  pci_irq_0 = device_create(pci_class, NULL, MKDEV(MAJOR(pci_dev_number), MINOR(pci_dev_number) + 1), NULL, "codec_irq_%d", 0);
  pci_irq_1 = device_create(pci_class, NULL, MKDEV(MAJOR(pci_dev_number), MINOR(pci_dev_number) + 2), NULL, "codec_irq_%d", 1);

  if (pci_register_driver( & pci_drv) < 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_DEVICES; i++)
      device_destroy(pci_class, MKDEV(pci_dev_number, i));
    goto free_dev_number;
  }

  return 0;
free_cdev:
    kobject_put( & driver_object - > kobj);
free_dev_number:
    unregister_chrdev_region(pci_dev_number, MAX_DEVICES);
  return -EIO;
}

static void __exit mod_exit(void) {
  int i = 0;
  pci_unregister_driver( & pci_drv);
  device_unregister(pci_prc);
  device_unregister(pci_irq_0);
  device_unregister(pci_irq_1);
  for (i = 0; i < MAX_DEVICES; i++) {
    device_destroy(pci_class, MKDEV(pci_dev_number, i));
  }
  class_destroy(pci_class);
  cdev_del(driver_object);
  unregister_chrdev_region(pci_dev_number, MAX_DEVICES);
}

module_init(mod_init);
module_exit(mod_exit);
```

Error handling routines could be better, but they don't get triggered anyway.

Comment: after first loading your module, can you successfully trigger an interrupt multiple times? after rmmod+insmod and triggering an interrupt, does any message appear on the console, or possibly /var/log/messages or output from `dmesg` regarding a stray/unclaimed interrupt?

Comment: Correct. And to make it work again, I have to restart my whole machine **but** leave the FPGA untouched. I assume that I do something wrong in the IRQ (de)initialization process ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found the cause of my problem. I took a look at the [PCI configuration space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_configuration_space) while executing each of the steps of my original post. The configuration space when interrupts are working:

```
# lspci -xxx | grep Xilinx
23:00.0 Memory controller: Xilinx Corporation Device 7024
00: ee 10 24 70 *07* 04 10 00 00 00 80 05 10 00 00 00
. . .
```

And when it's broken:

```
# lspci -xxx | grep Xilinx
23:00.0 Memory controller: Xilinx Corporation Device 7024
00: ee 10 24 70 *03* 04 10 00 00 00 80 05 10 00 00 00
. . .
```

What I found is that the [command register](https://wiki.qemu.org/images/f/f6/PCIvsPCIe.pdf#page=22) value changes after the kernel module reload (marked with *). When the interrupt works the command register value is `0x0407`, after the module reload it is `0x0403`. Why? I don't know. It is probably just the way the Xilinx [AXI Memory Mapped to PCIe](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/axi_pcie/v2_8/pg055-axi-bridge-pcie.pdf) core is implemented.

Anyway, you can set the values of the PCI configuration space using [`setpci(8)`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/setpci).

The wanted value of the command register is `0407` so you execute:

```
# setpci -d <vendor_id>:<device_id> command=0407

#read back to check if it worked
# sudo setpci -d <vendor_id>:<device_id> command
0407
```

Afterwards the interrupts are working again, and I do not need to reboot.

Within the kernel module you can e.g. use `pci_write_config_byte(...)` to set the command register (or any other) to the required value. The corresponding functions to access the configuration space can be found here: [Linux Device Drivers - Accessing the Configuration Space](https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch12.pdf#page=14)

Comment: You can also change bit 2 of the command register using the `pci_set_master` and `pci_clear_master` functions. The bit is to enable PCI bus mastering (for DMA), so I'm not sure why it makes a difference if you are not using DMA.

Comment: @IanAbbot, ah, it makes perfect sense, because device uses MSI. To the OP (Nico): Ian gave the right answer.

Comment: @0andriy Thanks for the enlightenment. I wasn't aware that MSI message delivery required bus mastering to be enabled.

Comment: @IanAbbott thanks for the tip. Currently, I am setting it in the way I described already. I am new to the topic of device drivers and PCIe, so I have a lot to learn. This should help me to take a closer look why and how these parameters interact.